# Firefox memory management

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-mediarecorder

I working with `MediaRecorder` API to record user video. Each `OnDataAvailable` add webm chunk to array (This is pure client solution).

After few tests of long time recordings we found problem on memory management in firefox: Fierfox eat all memory ,all chunks is stored locally in RAM. 
Chrome able to record 12-13 hours without any performance problem, all chunks is stored on disk in temp folder under "Chrome".

How can i solve this problem on firefox? LocalStorage is up to 10mb is not enough, server solutions is not good in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store blobs in [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), which is disk-backed.

Comment: Thanks. I checking IndexDB. Looks like this API does not have space limitation but it will ask for user permissions after first 50MB. It can be showstopper for me because this is screen recording...

Comment: Hi the8472. After storing blobs on IndexDB and get them by 'getAll' transaction. How can i play this blobs? If i using URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blobsFromIndexDB])) i still have my old problem... is start loading huge video blob into memory. On weak machines 2 hour .webm file lead to Firefox browser crush...

Comment: @OlegYudovich you only asked about recording. Playing it would be a separate question